# How can I expand ASP.NET Identity Samples with new role, e.g superuser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have downloaded this "Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples" https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples and can login as admin. when I'am logged in, I can create users.

How can I increase this? Say I want to create a new role superuser?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you can't just rely on modifying demo files to your needs. If you want to create roles you have to do some reading on the identity framework.

I highly recommend this article to get a better understanding of the basics.

http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx